# How can i encode to arabic language M-DOS file?

Tags: decode, encode, codepages

We have a very old account system named UTLVENUS for accounting we are moving to ORACLE for financing but we want old files to transfer there.

All TXT files have weird language and we want to transfer it to READABLE ARABIC.
Like this:

[image]

```
TRIAL BALANCE FOR MONTH            ‘  / •            Õ‡××À ªÔ ­×‰ºÇÕË ªÇÃ×Ë
!((                                      )!
‘•-‘-’                            44203++*                                 
‘—--˜======================================================================
 «ÑÕÆÇ    ¥Ì×××××××××××××××××××ÒÏÆÇ «×ÒÇ        ª××ÙÇ½       ª××Ã½Ë      ½×ÃÖÕÆÇ
================================================================================
44203000  162 ½ÑÔ °ÌÃÕÆÇ-DIVERSION ´›ÕÀË          Õ         Õ         Õ

44203100      ­ÃÕÇ½ÁÇ› ­ÃË›Ë‰ÆÇ ³ÃÕÌÖËÆÇ          Õ         Õ         Õ

44203110                    ´›ÕÀËÆÇ ¥ÉšË          Õ      ““‘”Õ      ““‘”Õ
44203111                  ©ÇÕÌºÃÇ ³ÃÕÌÖË          Õ    –Õ    –Õ
```

Comment: 1. Consult the system documentation to get the name of the codepage in which it creates these files. 2. Read the files using that codepage.

Comment: Try opening files using _Notepad++_ rather than _Notepad_… Notepad++ guesses encoding quite well.

Comment: I tried using Notepad ++ . tried all possible encoding . couldn't go .

Comment: Really needs help, if you could encode this that will be big thing . the software is very old .named: UTLVENUS . we couldn't find source for it . its works good in windows xp . but we want to have the data readable of the txt files

Comment: There is nothing to encode, it is already encoded (please see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). What you need to do is to tell the reader which encoding to use (also please see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Thanks for the article - good info . that the thing how to make it readable ??

Comment: Like explained, you are supposed to know what code page that is. Using Notepad++, I get Arabic-looking results [with ISO 8859-6](https://pastebin.com/p2p7cnHH) and [with Windows-1256](https://pastebin.com/ctbxgeBt). I don't know if any of these make sense as I don't read Arabic.